# How to return list of entities when I query to the view

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities that related with One to Many connection. One is Path another is Point, one path can have few points. And I have view on MySQL side that joined those tables using join table. I need to get the result of query to that view. Here is first

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "paths")
public class Path {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long pathID;
    @Column(name="path_name")
    private String pathName;
    @Column(name="path_type")
    private Long pathType;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="uid")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User owner;
    @Column(name="path_status")
    private Long pathStatus;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String pathDescription;
    @Column(name="created")
    private Long created;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.point",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PathPoints> pathPoints = new HashSet<PathPoints>();

    public Long getPathID(){
        return this.pathID;
    }
    public void setPathID(Long pathID){
        this.pathID = pathID;
    }

    public String getPathName(){
        return this.pathName;
    }
    public void setPathName(String pathName){
        this.pathName = pathName;
    }

    public Long getPathType(){
        return this.pathType;
    }
    public void setPathType(Long pathType){
        this.pathType = pathType;
    }

    public Long getPathStatus(){
        return this.pathStatus;
    }
    public void setPathStatus(Long pathStatus){
        this.pathStatus = pathStatus;
    }

    public String getPathDescription(){
        return this.pathDescription;
    }
    public void setPathDescription(String pathDescription){
        this.pathDescription = pathDescription;
    }

    public Long getCreated(){
        return this.created;
    }
    public void setCreated(Long created){
        this.created = created;
    }
    public Set<PathPoints> getPathPoints() {
        return pathPoints;
    }
    public void setPathPoints(Set<PathPoints> pathPoints) {
        this.pathPoints = pathPoints;
    }
    public User getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    public void setOwner(User owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

}
```

Here is second

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "path_points")
    @AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.point", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "point_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.path", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "path_id"))
    })
public class PathPoints{

    private PathPointID primaryKey = new PathPointID();

    private Long endTime;
    private Long  startTime;

    @Column(name="end_time")
    public Long getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }
    public void setEndTime(Long endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
    @Column(name="start_time")
    public Long getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }
    public void setStartTime(Long startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    @EmbeddedId
    public PathPointID getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }
    public void setPrimaryKey(PathPointID primaryKey) {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }
    @Transient
    public Point getPoint() {
        return primaryKey.getPoint();
    }
    public void setPoint(Point point) {
        this.primaryKey.setPoint(point);;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    public Path getPath() {
        return primaryKey.getPath();
    }
    public void setPath(Path path) {
        this.primaryKey.setPath(path);;
    }

}
```

And that is ID class

```
@Embeddable
public class PathPointID implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Point point;
private Path  path;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Point getPoint() {
    return point;
}
public void setPoint(Point point) {
    this.point = point;
}
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Path getPath() {
    return path;
}
public void setPath(Path path) {
    this.path = path;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create third entity class and make jpa/hibernate operations with it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "your_view_name")
public class YourView {

   @Column(name="someColumnFromYourView")
   private String someColumnFromYourView;

   @Transient
   private List<Point> points;
   ...
}
```

and then do

YourView view = ...//get this view data by some parameters
view.setPoints(yourDaoMethodToGetPoints(view));

you can see [this](https://github.com/ifnul/ums-backend/blob/master/is-lnu-domain/src/main/java/org/lnu/is/domain/user/group/UserGroupView.java) example. I'm using PostgreSQL and JPA 2.1 here.I wrote a view on the database and mapped it to JPA entity.There one thing you need to remember - you cannot do write operations on this view.

Comment: But I need to have access to Points as collection

Comment: As far as I remember - I couldn't achieve that. If you want to access to Points as collection - you need to have foreign key constraint - and there wouldn't be any FK constraint on your view. Understand the idea ?

Comment: Ok, I believe I understand but I need to search the Path with its Points using Points and Path name so I decide to use view. So is there a another way?